# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') even if I am not using the map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, ethers.js

So i have been coding a ethereum application which is used to make transactions using React, and ethers module.
And here is my code : (don't read the full code if not necessary, read the function : `sendTransactions`)

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
import {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css'
import {contractAddress, contractABI} from './utils/constants';
import {Form, WalletCardNotConnected, WalletCardConnected} from './components';


const App = () => {

  let isWalletConnected = true;
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
  const {ethereum} = window;
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const connectWallet = async () => {

    try {
      if (!ethereum) {
        return alert("Please install metamask");
      }
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({
        method : "eth_requestAccounts"
      });
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
      isWalletConnected = true;
      console.log(currentAccount);
    }catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error("No ethereum Object...");
    }
  };

  const getEthereumContract = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum, "any");
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionContact = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);
    return transactionContact;
  };

  const sendTransaction = async () => {

    if (document.querySelector('#to').value && document.querySelector('#amount').value) {
      const addressTo = document.querySelector('#to').value;
      const amount = document.querySelector('#amount').value;
      const transactionContract = await getEthereumContract();
      const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);
      await ethereum.request({
        method : "eth_sendTransaction",
        params : [{
            from : currentAccount,
            to : addressTo,
            gas : '0x5208',
            value : parsedAmount._hex,
        }]
    });
    const transactionHash = transactionContract.addToBlockChain(addressTo, parsedAmount);
    setIsLoading(true);
    console.log(`Loading : ${transactionHash.hash}`);
    await transactionHash.wait();
    console.log(`Success : ${transactionHash.hash}`);
    setIsLoading(false);


    }else {
      alert("details not enough for transactions.");
    }


  };

  return (
    <div>
      {currentAccount
        ? 
        //when the accounts is connected

        <div className="bg-white py-5 px-5 mx-5 my-5 shadow rounded-lg">
            <div className="bg-white">
                Balance : 
                <div className="inline shadow rounded-lg mx-2 my-2 py-1 px-1 bg-indigo-500 text-white">
                    27.483 
                </div>
                ETH
            </div>
            <div>
            <form action="" className='bg-white'>
              <label htmlFor="" className='block bg-white mt-5 font-semibold ' >To : </label>
              <input type="text" id='to' required className='bg-white mt-2 w-full border border-gray-300 rounded rounded-large shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 ' />
              <label htmlFor="" className='block bg-white mt-5 font-semibold' >Amount :  </label>
              <input type="text" id='amount' required className='bg-white mt-2 w-full border border-gray-300 rounded rounded-large shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500  ' />
              <div className='mt-5'>

                {isLoading
                  ? <button type="submit" disabled class=" w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-400 hover:bg-indigo-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-200" >Transaction Loading</button>
                  : <button type='button' class=" w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" onClick={sendTransaction}>Send Now</button>
                }

                {/* <button type="submit" class=" w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" onClick={sendTransaction}>Send Now</button> */}
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        : 
        //when the account in not connected
        

        <div className="bg-white shadow rounded-lg mt-10 mb-5 mr-5 ml-5 py-8 px-6">
            <h1 className="bg-white text-center">Wallet Not Connected</h1>
            <button type="submit" class=" mt-5 w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" onClick={connectWallet}>Connet Now</button>
        </div>


      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

whenever i click on the `Send` button i have a error which says :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at new Interface (interface.ts:100:47)
    at getInterface (index.ts:820:16)
    at new BaseContract (index.ts:662:94)
    at new Contract (index.ts:1140:7)
    at getEthereumContract (App.jsx?t=1679196209120:49:32)
    at sendTransaction (App.jsx?t=1679196209120:56:41)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
```

I have tried to figure out what is going on but I haven't figured it out yet, So i am expecting a solution that deals with the error
Thank you for reading, and praying for a solution.....

Comment: why is `getEthereumContract` an `async` function since you never `await` in it? perhaps you should await something there? (it doesn't look like you need to though)

Comment: I tried but it still isn't helping, waiting for more suggestions....

Comment: confirm all your arguments to `new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);` are valid, that seems to be the line of your code that results in the error

Comment: I have just confirmed it, there is no issue there according to me

Answer (score 1):

in the `sendTransaction` function, if it doesn't reach the `if` case, `transactionContract` is undefined since `transactionContract` is defined only in `if` clause.
so I think you need to define it before the `if` clause.

```
  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    const transactionContract = await getEthereumContract();
    if (document.querySelector('#to').value && document.querySelector('#amount').value) {
      const addressTo = document.querySelector('#to').value;
      const amount = document.querySelector('#amount').value;
      const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
```

I am not sure if it's a reason that it fails, but anyway it might be an issue.

Comment: your effort is highly appreciated sir.